# Extracting Float values from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, floating-point

I have a string like this `"Humidity: 14.00% Temperature:28.00 C"`.

I want to extract the two float values from the string, how can I do so?

Comment: The *proper* way to do this is to study the grammar of your string and build a *parser* (for example, `%` is a division by 100 operator and `C` denotes the Celcius temperature scheme). Alternatively, you could hack something out using `java.lang.String#substring` and `Float#parseFloat`. Plus one for asking for advice before launching on what turns out to be a terrible solution.

Comment: Do you need to associate the numbers with their labels, or can you count on them always being in the same order?  Will the numbers always contain decimal points?  If so, will there always be digits both before and after the decimal point?

Answer (score 7):

First, take a look at [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba)`s comment.
I have a straightforward way, but that is not clever or universal.

```
String[] array = string.replaceAll("[Humidity:|Temperature:|C]", "").split("%");
```

You will receive `String[]{"14.00", "28.00"}` and then you may convert these values of the array into `Float` by using `Float.parse()` or `Float.valueOf()` methods.

```
Arrays.stream(array).map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, using regex

```
String regex="([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)";
String input= "Humidity: 14.00% Temperature:28.00 C";

Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);

while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer : You should look at @Andrew Tobilko' s answer if you want some much cleaner and reusable code).

First you need to separate your string into two substrings. You can do this using 
`String a = yourString.substring(10,14);
String b =yourString.substring(29,33);`

Then, you use Float.parseFloat(String s) to extract a float from your strings :

```
Float c=Float.parseFloat(a); Float d= Float.parseFloat(b);
```

That is if your String is exactly the one that you wrote. Otherwise, you should make sure that you use the right indexes when you call String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex).