# How to block or omit charaters in EditText?

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext, block

Block or filter Character or String and "," while setting text to edittext.
for example if I get this string from list to display in edittext

```
edittext.setText("Total , 20.80");
```

My expected output should filter and display only **20.80** and omits  the following

- Total
- SPACE
- ,

before setting to editText

expected output

```
   edittext.setText("20.80");
```

Comment: They are many options but what I suggest you is use regex. You can start there https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern

Comment: This answer should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626445/9473786

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex for same.
Something like this.

```
String re = "^\\d{0,9}\\.\\d{1,4}$"
```