# Java how to extract floats from a string and display individually

Tags: java, string

I have a string and i would like to extract the floats in it. I have successfully done it using the matcher.group() function but i only want to display them separately. Here is my code

```
String regex="([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)";
String input= "You have bought USD 1.00 Whatsapp for 784024487. Your new wallet balance is USD 1.04. Happy Birthday EcoCash for turning 7years. Live Life the EcoCash Way.";

Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);

while(matcher.find())
  {
System.out.println("First float is "+matcher.group());
  }
}
```

The answer i get is : 
First float is 1.00 
First float is 1.04

But i want to say : 
First float is 1.00
Second Float is 1.04

How do i do that?

Comment: You are using `System.out.println("First float is "+matcher.group())` with hardcoded `First` in a `while` block. It is not a regex issue, hence removing `regex` tag.

Comment: It was answered earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608274/extracting-float-values-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Something like that maybe ?

```
int k = 1;
while(matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println("Float " + k + " is "+matcher.group());
   k++;
}
```

This will output something like: Float 1 is 1.00 Float 2 is 1.04

Comment: Even shorter : `System.out.println("Float " + (k++) + " is "+matcher.group());`

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Method to convert number to ordinal form then use it to display

```
public static String ordinal(int i) {
        String[] suffixes = new String[]{"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};
        switch (i % 100) {
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                return i + "th";
            default:
                return i + suffixes[i % 10];

        }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)";
        String input = "You have bought USD 1.00 Whatsapp for 784024487. Your new wallet balance is USD 1.04. Happy Birthday EcoCash for turning 7years. Live Life the EcoCash Way.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        int number = 1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(ordinal(number++) + " float is " + matcher.group());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a counter within loop, and based on counter write in output proper word. But rather start with displaying sth like "Float #n is: xxx" instead of words...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that returns postfix like `st`, `nd`, `rd` and use it in the code, e.g.:

```
private static String getPostFix(int number) {
    if(number % 10 == 1) {
        return "st";
    } else if(number % 2 == 0) {
        return "nd";
    } else if(number % 3 == 0) {
        return "rd";
    } else {
        return "th";
    }
}
```

The code would be:

```
String regex="([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)";
String input= "You have bought USD 1.00 Whatsapp for 784024487. Your new wallet balance is USD 1.04. Happy Birthday EcoCash for turning 7years. Live Life the EcoCash Way.";

Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);

int i=0;
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println((++i) + getPostFix(i) + " Float is :" + matcher.group());
}
```