# converting an alphanumeric string to double

Tags: java, string, string-conversion

I am trying to convert an alphanumeric string to double, and wondering if there is any simple method like `atoi` available for double in java

sample string: `"16.78%" => 16.78`

I tried `Double.parseDouble()`, but got the error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "16.78%"`.

Comment: Remove the percent sign before parsing.

Comment: "16.78" is not an "alphanumeric string". What do you mean by "alphanumeric"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting Float values from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608274/extracting-float-values-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: `atoi` is for integers. Perhaps you mean `atof`? Have you considered using class [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you still have the percent sign still in your string. `Double.parseDouble` doesn't tolerate anything in a string except for the number.

If you can't change the value of the string, try using;

```java
String sampleString = "16.78%"
Double.parseDouble(sampleString.replace("%", "")); // output: 16.78
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Astronomize for sharing your thoughts. I found something little more generic. and shared the same below.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
                 final Number number = new DecimalFormat().parse(alphanumericString);

                 if (number != null) {
                     result = number.floatValue();
                 } else {
                     throw new ParseException("Parser returned null", 0);
                 }
             } catch (final ParseException parseException) {
                 DLog.warnf(
                         "Encountered ParseException with converting %s to double. Exception message: %s",
                         alphanumericString, parseException.getMessage());
             }
```